# Create matrix of coefficients in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I have written a function that creates a matrix based on a polynomial of a given degree. I will ultimately use this to fit data, but the problem I am having is that I can not find a good way to create a coefficient matrix, such as:

My polynomial matrix: [1 x x^2 ... x^n] where n is the degree. The matrix consists of a number of these row entries, and what I want to do is to add coefficients to make it: [c_1 c_2*x ... c_n*x^n].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to do coefficient-wise multiplication between the row of your polynomial m-by-n matrix M (where m is the number of entries) and a 1-by-n vector C ?

> M.*(ones(m,1)*c)

Something like that ?
The part in parenthesis creates a m-by-n matrix repeating the row of coefficient, and the .* is the coefficient-wise multiplication.

Comment: Something like that. The result should be that the coefficients for each row are distinct, such that c_1 != c_2. But c_1 ... c_n are the the same for the whole row, essentially having an overdetermined matrix m>n. I realize I might be somewhat unclear, but I try as best I can!

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, the code I gave you should work, but it supposes the c_i are initially stored in a row. So the values are the same for the column, but change for each column. It just a matter of ordering, you can change with transposition (c' instad of c).

Comment: Oh yes, that's perfect. I mistakenly wrote row, but of course meant column. Thank you!